# How to resolved Fatal error: Call to undefined function login_header()?

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I am using `new user approval` plugin for user approve by admin and i also used `theme my login` plugin for user registration page and login page.

whenever i register new user from registration page and after registration i got error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function login_header() in.../plugins/new-user-approve/new-user-approve.php on line 617`

how can i resolved this error?

Comment: submit a bug report to the builder of the plugin, if you are the builder of the plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12784048#12784048. You could of course remove the function call